# How to associate multiple object instances via collections, 'late' dictionary, other ways?

Tags: excel, vba, class, dictionary, collections

I created an interface with one class.
I have a sub fetching multiple sheets, related named ranges and row amounts and I use this to loop through data which I need to group together.

Once the data is read row by row it instantiates the objects (the class pulls the data out of the cells via public init method which receives the range from the module) and I add them in the module to a simple collection without key. Until here everything is working.

In some cases I have object instances which I need to relate to each other as I need to treat them in a slightly different way in a later stage. (More columns in the outputtables afterwards.)
I added a unique identifier in my data only shared by the related instances, but I do not know how to proceed from here to create such an association.

This is the reading:

```vb
'Create solution is placed between Class creation and sub to define the target sheets & ranges
Option Explicit
Sub ReadData(Solutions As Collection)

Set Solutions = New Collection

Dim Solution As Variant
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim rowamount As Long

'define length of range
rowamount = Worksheets("source").Range("Named_ranges").Rows.Count

Dim myrow As Integer
Dim suspectWorksheet As String
Dim TargetWorksheet As Worksheet
Dim TargetWorkRange As String
Dim TargetRangeCount As Integer
Dim x As Integer

For myrow = 1 To rowamount

    'Identify the visible sheets from the source matrix & init worksheet
    suspectWorksheet = Worksheets("source").Range("Named_ranges").Cells(myrow, 1)
    Set TargetWorksheet = Worksheets(suspectWorksheet)
    If TargetWorksheet.Visible = True Then
    
        ' Init the range variable and get the max amount of lines to scan
        TargetWorkRange = Worksheets("source").Range("Named_ranges").Cells(myrow, 2)
        TargetRangeCount = Worksheets("source").Range("Named_ranges").Cells(myrow, 3)

        ' Start the lineloop to inject the data into the class
        For x = 1 To TargetRangeCount
            Debug.Print "Loop " & x
            'Is there an active line in the target range?
            If Worksheets(suspectWorksheet).Range(TargetWorkRange).Cells(x + 1, 1) > 0 Then
                Set rng = Worksheets(suspectWorksheet).Range(TargetWorkRange).Resize(1, 60).Offset(x, 0)
                Set Solution = solutionClassFactory(rng)
                Solutions.Add Solution
                 
                'Solution.PrintOut
            End If
        Next x
    End If
Next myrow

Set TargetWorksheet = Nothing
End Sub

' Checks the type of solution and returns into a class
Function solutionClassFactory(rng As Range) As Variant

Dim solutionType As String

solutionType = rng.Cells(1, 51)

Dim Solution As Variant
Select Case solutionType
    Case "something":
        Set Solution = New something
End Select

Solution.Init rng

' solution is returned to be added to the main collection
Set solutionClassFactory = Solution

End Function
```

This is the writing part:

```vb
Sub Create()
Dim Solution As Variant
Dim Solutions As Collection
Dim TargetWorksheet As String
Dim i As Integer
'Define to which sheet it needs to be written
TargetWorksheet = "sheet"

ReadData Solutions
i = 5

For Each Solution In Solutions

    Worksheets(TargetWorksheet).Cells(i, 1) = Solution.amount
    'more

    i = i +1

Next Solution

End Sub
```

I don't want to revert to loops in loops for performance reasons.

Class Code

```vb
' class derived from Solution interface
Option Explicit

 ' Implements Solution interfacs
Implements Solution

Private amount_ As Integer
Private amountRef_ As String

Private Sub Class_Initialize()

End Sub

Public Sub Init(rng As Range)
    amount_ = rng.Cells(1, 1)
    amountRef_ = "'" & rng.Parent.Name & "'!" & rng.Columns.Item(1).address
End Sub

Public Sub PrintOut()
Debug.Print amount_, TypeName(Me), linekey_ & vbNewLine;
Debug.Print amountRef_, TypeName(Me), linekeyRef_ & vbNewLine;
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    ' Debug.Print "WAN class instance deleted"
End Sub

Public Property Get amount() As Integer
    amount = amount_
End Property

Public Property Let amount(ByVal Value As Integer)
    amount = amount_
End Property

Public Property Get linekeyRef() As String
    linekeyRef = linekeyRef_
End Property

Public Property Let linekeyRef(ByVal Value As String)
    linekeyRef = linekeyRef_
End Property

' Implement required interface properties
Private Property Get Solution_address() As String
    Solution_address = address
End Property
```

Comment: How are you creating the "unique identifier" ?

Comment: Just a property of the class related to a cell in the range being imported in excelsheet, like any other property.

Comment: Maybe I should rephrase what I want to achieve. I would like to have for example multiple additional collections with only these object instances in them which are grouped together by this property. so property important would be 2 instances, property not important would be 3 instances and all other instances should still be in the original solutions collection.. Hope this makes sense :)

Comment: I think I understand what you want and a Dictionary would be one solution but because you have shown only part of your code I am not sure you are utilising the full benefits of class objects. The danger is over-complication when you have a hybrid of OOP and structured programming.

Comment: Honestly I think you are right.. Basically apart from the init method getting the range and cell values, I'm not doing a lot with it in the class itself. I'm basically shadowing both values and cell references (to create dynamic and static sheets). I am however trying to create something robust and flexible. But got the message so will add the code with reduced variables.

Comment: ok I went all in and updated the code. Had to ommit some stuff but left all the important pieces there. I thought a lot about it so I hope it's not too bad  ;-)

Comment: Seems like you need a containing "Data" class which (1) holds your `Solutions` collection (2) has a dictionary with your "key" values which each map to a collection referencing the relevant items from the `Solutions` collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a Dictionary Object with your unique id as the key and a collection of objects as the values. For example, some top level code to create object and invoke methods.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Process()

   Dim rep As reporter
   Set rep = New reporter
   Set rep.SourceRng = Sheets("source").Range("Named_ranges")
   rep.readata
   MsgBox rep.linecount & " lines read"
   
   Set rep.DestRng = Sheets("Sheet5").Range("A1")
   rep.writedata
  
   Set rep.DestRng = Sheets("Sheet6").Range("A1")
   rep.writedata_bytyp
   MsgBox "Done"
   
End Sub
```

The `Solution` class

```
Public amount As Long
Public ref As String
Public typ As String
```

a `Reporter` class to hold the dictionary and collection

```
Private Solutions As New Collection
Private Things As Object
Public SourceRng As Range
Public DestRng As Range
Public linecount As Long
Const COL_TYPE = "AY" '51

Sub readata()

   Dim i As Long, obj As Solution, v
   Dim ws As Worksheet, sRng As String, rng As Range
   Dim r As Long, rowcount As Long
   Set Things = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
   
   For i = 1 To SourceRng.Rows.Count
        Set ws = Sheets(SourceRng.Cells(i, 1).Value2)
        sRng = SourceRng.Cells(i, 2)
        rowcount = SourceRng.Cells(i, 3)
        
        If ws.Visible = True Then
            Set rng = ws.Range(sRng)
            For r = 2 To rowcount + 1
            
                v = rng.Cells(r, 1).Value2
                If v > 0 Then
                      
                    Set obj = New Solution
                    obj.amount = v
                    obj.typ = Trim(rng.Cells(r, COL_TYPE))
                    obj.ref = ws.Name & "!" & rng.Cells(r, 1).Address
                    Solutions.Add obj
                    
                    If Not Things.exists(obj.typ) Then
                        Things.Add obj.typ, New Collection
                    End If
                    Things(obj.typ).Add obj
                    linecount = linecount + 1
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Sub writedata()
    Dim i As Long, obj
    With DestRng
        For Each obj In Solutions
           i = i + 1
           .Cells(i, 1) = obj.amount
           .Cells(i, 2) = obj.typ
           .Cells(i, 3) = obj.ref
        Next
    End With
End Sub

Sub writedata_bytyp()
    Dim i As Long, key, obj
    With DestRng
        For Each key In Things.keys
            i = i + 1
            .Cells(i, 1) = key
            For Each obj In Things(key)
                i = i + 1
                .Cells(i, 2) = obj.amount
                .Cells(i, 3) = obj.typ
                .Cells(i, 4) = obj.ref
            Next
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: When I read through the code it does seem to do what I want. I will test and let you know . Many thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to cast a vote, but this is excellent coding. This works like a charm, it's simplified, powerful yet easy to manage in the future. So a big vote from me :)